# Real Analytic Diffeomorphism Book Suggestion

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest me some basic book on real analytic diffeomorphisms. I have seen a post on real analytic diffeomorphisms in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913147/existence-of-continuous-and-analytic-function). I can't understand it. Kindly suggest me some book on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis* by Andreas Kriegl and Peter W. Michor